# Convert List of key - value Object pairs to simple Multimap using Java 8 API

Tags: java

Having list of key - values:

```
public class KeyValue {

    private Long key;

    private Long value;

    public KeyValue(long key, long value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    } 

    //getters, setters, toStrings...
}
```

...

```
    List<KeyValue> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(new KeyValue(15, 10));
    values.add(new KeyValue(15, 12));
    values.add(new KeyValue(25, 13));
    values.add(new KeyValue(25, 15));
```

How to convert it to Multimap using Java 8 API?

Procedural way:

```
    Map<Long, List<Long>> keyValsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (KeyValue dto : values) {
        if (keyValsMap.containsKey(dto.getKey())) {
            keyValsMap.get(dto.getKey()).add(dto.getValue());
        } else {
            List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(dto.getValue());
            keyValsMap.put(dto.getKey(), list);
        }
    }
```

Result:

{25=[13, 15], 15=[10, 12]}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector allows you to do:

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> result = values.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(KeyValue::getKey,
         Collectors.mapping(KeyValue::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Then the [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector converts the `KeyValue` objects into their respective values.